# Playing next video while casting results in an error

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm developing an Android TV app and I'm trying to implement casting straight to my native app. I'm using this as a reference: https://github.com/android/tv-samples/tree/main/ReferenceAppKotlin

I created an application on cast.google.com, pointed it to the package of the Android TV reference app. I changed and build the sample sender app to use a my own app id: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android.

When modifying the code in the Reference TV app a bit to properly play the mediastream, sent from the CastVideos app, casting works perfectly. The only thing that's not working, is playing the next item. Whenever I click, add to queue, or play now, I see these two errors/warnings in Logcat:

```
2024-01-27 21:40:07.796 21680-21680 MediaCommandCb          com.android.tv.reference             E  Default media command handling returns failure
2024-01-27 21:40:07.799 21680-21680 ReceiverMediaChannel    com.android.tv.reference             W  Failed to execute media control message
```

I tried Googling these errors but no results. Any idea how to properly play the next video? Or where this error might occur in which library?